# Can a Huffman code lead to two different translation?

Tags: algorithms

Is it a property of Huffman code to always be translated in one way? Or there are examples where a single piece of binary code can be interpreted in two different ways?

For instance: let code (1001010) be sent to a computer. 
Is it possible that the computer recognizes the code in different ways? 
Eg (100,1010) or (1001,010)

Answer (score 4):

If they are ambiguous, then you have created the codes wrong.  In a true Huffman code, no code sequence can ever also be the prefix of another.  So if 100 is a valid code, then 1001 cannot be.

Or, to put it another way, when you reach the end of a code word, then you should know that you have reached the end, ready to start reading the next one.

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)

Answer (score 2):

Huffman codes are a case of [Prefix codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code), meaning that no code sequence contains a prefix that is also a valid code sequence.

For example, if `1001010` was a valid code sequence in your Huffman encoding, then none of these prefixes are valid code sequences:

```
1001010
100101
10010
1001
100
10
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just have the encoded data. You need to know which byte is encoded how. The easiest way to do this is storing the lengths of each byte, so the decoding table can be created from this.

Once you have the decoding table, there is only one way to translate the data.

As a simplified example, if you had just four different values, then the code lengths could be (2, 2, 2, 2) or (1, 2, 3, 3), each with the byte lengths in any order, for example (2, 3, 1, 3). With that example, the bit strings would be 00, 010, 1, and 011.